# enlarge bounding box from a smaller one in GDAL

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, extents, gdal-translate

I have a small raster tiff and I want copy its data in a new raster with a bigger bbox. So is it possible, via a GDAL command, to enlarge a bounding box maintaining same pixel locations from the original raster? In output I expect something like a padded image filled of nodata value around the original bbox.

Comment: Use gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html with -projwin. Adjust the new extent to suit with pixel size to avoid resampling.

Comment: @user30184 I've already tried but it doesn't work when dest bbox is bigger than src.

Comment: Works for me with GDAL 2.3-dev. I must write an answer because my test does not fit into a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with GDAL 2.3-dev you can use gdal_translate with enlarged "projwin". See below how a 10 by 10 pixel image with pixel size of 100x100 m is converted into a 20 by 20 pixel image.

```
gdalinfo small.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: small.tif
Size is 10, 10
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (950.000000000000000,1050.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (100.000000000000000,-100.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=120
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=120
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (     950.000,    1050.000)
Lower Left  (     950.000,      50.000)
Upper Right (    1950.000,    1050.000)
Lower Right (    1950.000,      50.000)
Center      (    1450.000,     550.000)
Band 1 Block=10x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=10x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=10x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue

gdal_translate -projwin 0 2000 2000 0 small.tif bigger.tif
Input file size is 10, 10
Computed -srcwin -9 -9 20 20 from projected window.
Warning: Computed -srcwin -9 -9 20 20 falls partially outside raster extent.
Going on however.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

gdalinfo bigger.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: bigger.tif
Size is 20, 20
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (50.000000000000000,1950.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (100.000000000000000,-100.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=120
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=120
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (      50.000,    1950.000)
Lower Left  (  50.0000000, -50.0000000)
Upper Right (    2050.000,    1950.000)
Lower Right (    2050.000,     -50.000)
Center      (    1050.000,     950.000)
Band 1 Block=20x20 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=20x20 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=20x20 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

For defining black pixels to mean nodata use `-a_nodata 0`
Another option is to use gdalwarp with -te (target extent) parameter http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html.