# Enlarge numpy array to fill/pad bounds in rasterio whilst keeping existing data intact

Tags: raster, gdal, rasterio, numpy

I'm looking to do what [this question and answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206161/enlarge-bounding-box-from-a-smaller-one-in-gdal) is doing using `gdal_translate` / `gdal_warp`, but in Rasterio. Does anyone know of a way? I can't find anything in the rasterio.warp.reproject module that seemed to do what I was after. I am aware you can do it [like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444189/raster-calculation-with-rasters-of-different-extent-using-rasterio) using a larger window and `boundless=True`, but I would prefer to do it using the raw numpy array only if possible (plus the requisite transforms etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Reading a window would be easy, and you can create a dataset in memory if you don't already have one that contains what's in your numpy array.

But if you want to stick closer to numpy, you can certainly just initialize a larger array then use the bounds and pixel sizes to work out where to insert the original.

```py
import rasterio
import numpy as np

from rasterio import transform, dtypes, windows


def main():
    np.random.seed(0)

    src_w = src_h = 10
    src_arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, src_w * src_h, np.uint8)
    src_arr = src_arr.reshape((src_h, src_w))

    src_bounds = (100, 1000, 200, 1100)
    dst_bounds = (50, 900, 250, 1200)

    src_xform = transform.from_bounds(*src_bounds, src_w, src_h)

    # Option A: create an in-memory dataset from the numpy array, then read windows
    with rasterio.MemoryFile() as mf:
        with mf.open(driver='GTiff', width=10, height=10, count=1, dtype=dtypes.uint8, transform=src_xform) as src_ds:
            src_ds.write(src_arr, 1)

        with mf.open() as src_ds:
            window = rasterio.windows.from_bounds(*dst_bounds, transform=src_ds.transform)
            dst_arr_a = src_ds.read(window=window, boundless=True)

        # Option B: create your own target array and figure out where to insert the original
        dst_w = int((dst_bounds[2] - dst_bounds[0]) / src_ds.res[0])
        dst_h = int((dst_bounds[3] - dst_bounds[1]) / src_ds.res[1])
        offset_y = int((dst_bounds[3] - src_bounds[3]) / src_ds.res[1])
        offset_x = int((src_bounds[0] - dst_bounds[0]) / src_ds.res[0])
        dst_arr_b = np.zeros((dst_h, dst_w), dtype=np.uint8)
        dst_arr_b[offset_y:offset_y+src_h, offset_x:offset_x+src_w] = src_arr

    # Ensure these two methods agree
    assert np.all(dst_arr_a == dst_arr_b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it purely with Rasterio APIs - thanks to Sean Gillies, the maintainer of the library, for helping me out with this:

(where bounds is a simple dataclass and the `self` object holds transform and crs properties, and the `data` member is an numpy ndarray object)

```
extent=Bounds(xmin=20, ymin=56, xmax=38, ymax=70)
dst_transform = Affine(self.transform.a, 0, extent.xmin, 0, self.transform.e, extent.ymax)
dst_width = max(int(round((extent.xmax - extent.xmin) / self.transform.a)), 1)
dst_height = max(int(round((extent.ymax - extent.ymin) / -self.transform.e)), 1)
new_data, transform = warp.reproject(
            source=self.data,
            destination=np.zeros(shape=(dst_height, dst_width)),
            src_transform=self.transform,
            dst_transform=dst_transform,
            src_crs=self.crs,
            dst_crs=self.crs,
            src_nodata=np.nan,
            dst_nodata=np.nan,
        )
```

I think the pure numpy way (Option B above) is probably quicker though, thank you @mikewatt

Comment: Nice.  `self.data` is a numpy array in this example?  Didn't know you could pass one right in

Comment: yes it is an ndarray - will clarify in the answer